# Misplaced \noalign at tabu environment

Tags: tables, tabu

I was testing some commands on ShareLatex, and while creating a 'tabu' environment, I came across an error: 'Misplaced \noalign'

[image: Error related to tabu environment]

I searched here in StackExchange about this error and read lots of answered questions, but none of them could solve my problem.
I am pasting the code below, and I beg you to help me. Probably, there is something that my eyes didn't see.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{txfonts}  
\usepackage{mathdots}  
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{tabu}  
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}  
\usepackage{geometry}  
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm,right=25mm}  
\providecommand{\sin}{} \renewcommand{\sin}{\hspace{2pt}\mathrm{sen}}  
\providecommand{\tan}{} \renewcommand{\tan}{\hspace{2pt}\mathrm{tg}}  
\usepackage{calc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\definecolorset{RGB}{}{}{bio,149,193,0;qui,0,141,54;biot,226,239,217}  
\setlength\parindent{0cm}  


\begin{document}

\begin{center}  
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}  

\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}  
\hline  
\rowcolor{bio} \rowfont{\color{white} \bfseries} Caráter & Grupo A & Grupo B & Grupo C & Grupo D & Grupo E & Grupo F & Grupo G \\ \hline  
\rowfont{\bfseries}                 1 & X & X & X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline  
\rowcolor{biot} \rowfont{\bfseries} 2 &   & X & X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline  
\rowfont{\bfseries}                 3 &   &   & X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline  
\rowcolor{biot} \rowfont{\bfseries} 4 &   &   &   & X & X & X & X \\ \hline  
\rowfont{\bfseries}                 5 &   &   &   & X & X &   &   \\ \hline  
\rowcolor{biot} \rowfont{\bfseries} 6 &   &   &   &   &   & X & X \\ \hline  
\end{tabu}  

\end{center}  

\end{document}
```

Thank you who tried to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `\rowcolor` has to come after `\rowfont` for whatever reason:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolorset{RGB}{}{}{bio,149,193,0;qui,0,141,54;biot,226,239,217}
\setlength\parindent{0cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}

\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowfont{\color{white} \bfseries}\rowcolor{bio}  Caráter & Grupo A & Grupo B & Grupo C & Grupo D & Grupo E & Grupo F & Grupo G \\ \hline
\rowfont{\bfseries}                 1 & X & X & X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
\rowfont{\bfseries}\rowcolor{biot}  2 &   & X & X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
\rowfont{\bfseries}                 3 &   &   & X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
\rowfont{\bfseries}\rowcolor{biot}  4 &   &   &   & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
\rowfont{\bfseries}                 5 &   &   &   & X & X &   &   \\ \hline
\rowfont{\bfseries}\rowcolor{biot}  6 &   &   &   &   &   & X & X \\ \hline
\end{tabu}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```